# Does performance diminish by having so many methods related to the mongoose scheme?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose

A quick question.
If I create many methods and static functions of the scheme with mongoose, can these functions decrease performance, for example in research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many? I think, every method is an additional constant in the document object. It needs additional bytes of RAM to store and CPU ticks to create. If you had millions of docs you could use lean() call to create a plain JS object without any overhead. 
In fact, creating a mongoose doc object is an expensive operation but remember that you save tons of your coding time.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can six methods of the scheme be all right? How much is the maximum order of greatness of the functions?

Comment: I think six is all right. If you had hundreds or thousands of methods, how would you manage them?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is a MongoDB object modeling tool designed to work in an asynchronous environment. Its performance depends on your schema model, schema file size, the database maintenance and how many routes use this schema model. If you need to use many methods and static functions then you use it. I hope you should follow the mongoose documentation and got a good result for your project or work.

Here the link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guides.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, you have been very helpful

Comment: Welcome to appreciate your project.